# Events from Local MS office application to browser

Tags: javascript, vsto, ms-office

We have a content management solution and we host files.

Our server side act as a MS WEBDAV server .

Our browser side java script based application shows the files stored in our servers.

Whenever an user click on a document in our browser application , we form the ms office URIs and Local ms office installation opens. Thereafter the DAV communication happens between the local office application and our server side.

Now i want to share some information/state between the local office application and the client side browser which actually helped to open the file.

Is it possible on the browser side to listen to some events generated by office application for e.g. on save ?

Office generates event on save but they remain on the realm of Office products. How to propagate this event to the browser application running ?

I can probably develop a VSTO add in , capture the event, wrap the event to a messsage bus and let my browser application listen to that message bus but this seems pretty complex.

Also i don't have the option to send any notification from my server side to client side .

Best Regards,

Saurav

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to create a VSTO add-in that talks directly with a server-side service.

You have a few options on how to implement this. I would try to create a WebSocket bridge, which forwards messages between the VSTO add-in and your web application client-side code. I would start by looking at using something like [websockify](https://github.com/novnc/websockify).

Alternatively, you could create a simple HTTP web service that can be called by both parties and then have the javascript code poll for updates periodically.

Or you could even go for a hybrid of these two options, where the VSTO add-in uses a standard HTTP service call and your javascript uses WebSockets to receive updates from the same service.

This new service could easily sit alongside your main web application. Maybe, the web methods could just be part of your web application.

It is quite straight forward... You just need to figure out how you are going to keep a reference of the document so that both parties can refer to it, unmistakenly. I would consider using a file property or document metadata property.